# Python Flask Web App Navigation Without Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I Want to develop a flask navigation bar like Google Contacts.

[image: Sample Picture]

I Want to Render a particular HTML page inside the red box (as in the picture) when I click each of the navigation buttons (the green box as in picture) without refreshing the page.

I have already tried using

> {% extends "layout.html" %}

Comment: How about using ajax and rendering the content inside the red box after getting the data.

Comment: Such single page applications are done in Javascript. Flask is only serving as a backend for the data in this case.

Comment: so how did they navigate to each views through url.eg:https://contacts.google.com/frequent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Klaus D. mentioned in the comments section, what you want to achieve can be done using Javascript only. Maybe your question were

> How can I send a request to my server-side (to get or fetch some information) and receive back a response on the client-side without having to refresh the page unlike the `POST` method usually does?

I will try to address the aforementioned question because that's probably your case.

**A potential solution**

Use Ajax for this. Build a function that sends a payload with certain information to the server and once you receive back the response you use that data to dynamically modify the part of the web-page you desire to modify.

Let's first build the right context for the problem. Let's assume you want to filter some projects by their category and you let the user decide. That's the idea of AJAX, the user can send and retrieve data from a server asynchronously.

**HTML (div to be modified)**

```
<div class="row" id="construction-projects"></div>
```

**Javascript (Client-side)**

```
$.post('/search_pill', {
    category: category, // <---- This is the info payload you send to the server.
  }).done(function(data){ // <!--- This is a callback that is being called after the server finished with the request.
    // Here you dynamically change parts of your content, in this case we modify the construction-projects container.
    $('#construction-projects').html(data.result.map(item => `
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card card-plain card-blog">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h6 class="card-category text-info">${category}</h6>
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#pablo">${item.title_intro.substring(0, 40)}...</a>
                </h4>
                <p class="card-description">
                  ${item.description_intro.substring(0, 80)}... <br>
                  <a href="#pablo"> Read More </a>
                </p>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `))
    
  }).fail(function(){
    console.log('error') // <!---- This is the callback being called if there are Internal Server problems.
  });
}
```

Build a function that will fetch the current page via ajax, but not the whole page, just the div in question from the server. The data will then (again via jQuery) be put inside the same div in question and replace old content with new one.

**Flask (Server-side)**

```
''' Ajax path for filtering between project Categories. '''
@bp.route('/search_pill', methods=['POST'])
def search_pill():
    category = request.form['category']
    current_page = int(request.form['current_page'])
    
    ## Search in your database and send back the serialized object.

    return jsonify(result = [p.serialize() for p in project_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @CaffeinatedCod3r,@Klaus D and @newbie99 for your answers.

I Figured it out. instead of using Flask we can use Angular JS Routing for navigation.

Here is the example that i referred:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/!">Main</a></p>

<a href="banana">Banana</a>
<a href="tomato">Tomato</a>

<p>Click on the links to change the content.</p>

<p>Use the "otherwise" method to define what to display when none of the links are clicked.</p>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/banana", {
        template : "<h1>Banana</h1><p>Bananas contain around 75% water.</p>"
    })
    .when("/tomato", {
        template : "<h1>Tomato</h1><p>Tomatoes contain around 95% water.</p>"
    })
    .otherwise({
        template : "<h1>Nothing</h1><p>Nothing has been selected</p>"
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

By Using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` i was able to remove the # from the URL.